# NeoVIM | E81: Using <SID> not in a script context

Tags: neovim

I'm trying to make g++ run as a function `:call` in vim> For some reason that I don't understand vim throws me an E81 error when I try to execute the `s:compile_run_cpp()` function.

```
function! s:compile_run_cpp() abort
  let src_path = expand('%:p:~')
  let src_noext = expand('%:p:~:r')
  " The building flags
  let _flag = '-Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -O2'

  if executable('clang++')
    let prog = 'clang++'
  elseif executable('g++')
    let prog = 'g++'
  else
    echoerr 'No compiler found!'
  endif
  call s:create_term_buf('v', 80)
  execute printf('term %s %s %s -o %s && %s', prog, _flag, src_path, src_noext, src_noext)
  startinsert
endfunction

function s:create_term_buf(_type, size) abort
  set splitbelow
  set splitright
  if a:_type ==# 'v'
    vnew
  else
    new
  endif
  execute 'resize ' . a:size
endfunction
```

Comment: did you checked by moving the function to global scope

Comment: Sorry I'm new to vim; how do I move the function to a global scope.

Comment: you just need to change `s:` to `g:`

Comment: please also add how you are mapping the call to function.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that question, what do you want to know? It's in a script file in the autoload folder and I'm calling it by typing call s:compile_run_cpp()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using autoload instead of `.vimrc` then change your function name to `filename#function_name` for eg: if you file name is `compile.vim` and the function name is `compile_run_cpp` then the function name would be `compile#compile_run_cpp` then you can easily call it with `:call compile#compile_run_cpp()`

```
function! compile#compile_run_cpp() abort
  let src_path = expand('%:p:~')
  let src_noext = expand('%:p:~:r')
  " The building flags
  let _flag = '-Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -O2'

  if executable('clang++')
    let prog = 'clang++'
  elseif executable('g++')
    let prog = 'g++'
  else
    echoerr 'No compiler found!'
  endif
  call s:create_term_buf('v', 80)
  execute printf('term %s %s %s -o %s && %s', prog, _flag, src_path, src_noext, src_noext)
  startinsert
endfunction

function s:create_term_buf(_type, size) abort
  set splitbelow
  set splitright
  if a:_type ==# 'v'
    vnew
  else
    new
  endif
  execute 'resize ' . a:size
endfunction
```

---

In case you are using `.vimrc`

Try changing this:

```
call s:create_term_buf('v', 80)
```

to this:

```
call <SID>create_term_buf('v', 80)
```

Note:

- Conversion for function naming used by other programmers. for eg: `create_term_buf` to `Create_term_buf`
- Don't scope a function if you want to call it from other script like `compile_run_cpp`.

Comment: I tried this and I still get exactly the same error

Comment: @boomcreeper11 did you capitalized the function name

Comment: Yes, I capitalised the name

Comment: @boomcreeper11 please check updated answer